# how to connect to .db // wordpress sqlite php

Tags: php, wordpress, sqlite

I have .db file format sqlite3. I am developing a wordpress web which is all mysql. How can I connect to that .db file and edit it with php? Also that .db file is in ftp server.

I tried something like this

```
$db = new SQLite3('path/to/db.db');
```

but I am getting error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file'

guessing I need to install it somehow?

Comment: How can you connect to which database? Your SQLite database or the WordPress MySQL database?

Comment: my sqlite database

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php or, if you must, https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: yeah I tried something like this
$db = new SQLite3('path/to/db.db');
but I am getting error:
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file'

guessing I need to install it somehow?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information to it. But it looks like your database isn't located where you think it is.

Comment: im 100% sure that it's located where I directed

Comment: I read that this kind of error may be because of permissions. something in php.ini but didn't manage to figure it out.

Comment: Does [`file_exists('path/to/db.db');`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) return `true` or `false`?

Comment: Yes, it could be related to file permissions. Of course whatever user is running PHP needs to be able to read the file.

Comment: it returns 1 so it's true

Comment: And yet the file should be readable or editable. I asked my server host about that.